# How to do ANCOVA in R?

Tags: r, statistics, covariance, anova

I have a dataframe with three columns: data$input, data$output and data$category. Both input and output are continuous numerics, and categories are discrete characters. I know ANCOVA is a method that analyzes the effect of input on output while controlling for the effect of category. However I could not find the exact command to do for this online.

Here is a small example of how the data would look like:

```
   input output category

1    0.4   0.55        A

2    0.5   0.66        A

3    0.6   0.57        A

4    0.3   0.23        B

5    0.4   0.53        B

6    0.7   0.75        B

7    1.1   1.31        C

8    0.9   1.01        C

9    0.8   0.58        C

10   0.5   0.34        C
```

What commands should I input to perform the ANCOVA? Thank you very much!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use the function `lm`, which runs a linear regression (in the end, ANOVA and ANCOVA are just restricted versions of the linear model).

> mod <- lm(output ~ input + category, data=data)

You can view the output with the `summary` function

> summary(mod)

If you really need to have the output 'ANOVA style', then you can apply the function `anova` on the model created (I personally find the `lm` output more informative, but maybe you have specific restrictions).

> anova(mod)

Comment: It seems that the order is important. if it is "input + category" it doesn't control for the input effect for category, but if "category + input" it removes all category-caused effects first.

Comment: Yes, the order is important depending on your research question, but only if you enter your variables hierarchically (then you can focus on changes in R2). So indeed if the variable of interest is `input`, it should be entered in a second step.

Comment: @msoftrain HIERARCHICALLY means ordered factor?